# How can I get only rgb of plt.imread?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Hello I am reading an image with

```
plt.imread('photo.png')
```

and this returns the following shape:

100, 100, 4

What can I do to only get the rgb, that is to say

100, 100, 3

Comment: Consider using `OpenCV` for image reading/writing/processing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try getting the first three values i.e. the RGB sequence (100, 100, 3) from the RGBA sequences (100, 100, 4) using the following where you leave out the alpha parameter. As per the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imread.html), `imread` returns (M, N, 3) for RGB images and (M, N, 4) for RGBA images.

```
rgb = plt.imread('photo.png')[:,:,:3]
```